# Import excel cell data to different sheet without removing formatting

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets. The cells in the one sheet contains only simple numbers and strings. The other one has a lot of formatting and style. I want to move the data in sheet 1 to sheet 2 and have sheet 2 retain its format.

Essentially, if I write a number 1 in cell A1 in sheet 1, and color cell A1 in sheet 2 blue, I want to import the 1 from sheet 1 to sheet 2, and keep the colouring. I wish to do this for the whole sheet, matching cells and moving only the data.

Is this possible? I've tried using various things like saving the table format and the format painter but they do not produce the results I seek.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure which way you're trying to move data so i'll try and explain both:

If you want to copy the values from sheet 1 into sheet 2 exactly then try:

**Paste Special - Values**. You can do this easily with a keyboard shortcut of `Ctrl+Alt+V` and then pressing `V` and enter. More info [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-paste-special-options-c31b7c9e-69ce-4b60-8c3a-dc5ea10d872c)

If you want to keep the data in sheet 1 but move formatting from sheet 2 across, then use:

Otherwise reading a bit more into **Format Painter** may be useful.
Microsoft has some instructions how to use this in detail [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-formatting-using-the-format-painter-b9fe82ea-c0a0-41de-837b-d2f15dd41ea9). Otherwise there are some third party plugins such as Kutools that have more advanced features

Hope I've helped!